# C# Error : Unhandled exception System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

I have been trying to remove this error for a long time. I have used int.parse instead of Convert.ToInt32 and still no output. Can someone tell me what's the error?

```
int i;
int w, x, y, z;
w = Convert.ToInt32("Grr");
x = Convert.ToInt32("Rawr");
y = Convert.ToInt32("Ssss");
z = Convert.ToInt32("Chirp");

int[] a = new int[100];
for (i = 0; i <= a.Length; i++)
{

    a[i] = Console.Read();
    if (a[i] == w)
    {
        Console.Write("Lion ");
    }
    else if (a[i] == x)
    {
        Console.Write("Tiger ");
    }
    else if (a[i] == y)
    {
        Console.Write("Snake ");
    }
    else if (a[i] == z)
    {
        Console.Write("Bird ");
    }
}
```

Comment: All those strings are incapable of being converted to `Int32`. What integer value do you expect "Grr", for example, to give you?

Comment: Use a `string[]` array, not integers.  You're not trying to compare numbers here.

Comment: And eventually, you'll find that `Read` is not what you want (it returns a single `char` value as `int`) and you want `ReadLine` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert a string to int and recognizing whether it matches the int value of the sound the animal is making after user input. But, afaik, it shouldn't work with the kinds of strings you're supplying it - there is no way you can make

```
 int.Parse("Grr");
```

to not throw an exception.

If you want to convert a string like that into integer values, and check if it matches some other value you can work around this:

```
string value = "9quali52ty3";

// Convert the string into a byte[].
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
```

You now have an array of the ASCII value of the bytes, like this:

57 113 117 97 108 105 53 50 116 121 51
*Maybe this will help.*

For **int.Parse:**
It **will** work like this

```
w=Int.Parse("353");
```

or

```
string foo = "353;
int bar = int.Parse(foo);
```

Even though 353 is of type string, what it contains is a **valid** number.
Using int.Parse will throw an exception if you supply it with a string that doesn't contain what is a valid number.

So, IF you are **NOT SURE** whether the string has a parsable int, you use this:

```
int bar;
int.TryParse(foo, out bar);
```

This will parse if it can, and if it doesn't - it will NOT throw an exception.
The return value will be a boolean indicating whether the TryParse function worked, like so:

```
string foo="353";

if(int.TryParse(foo, out int bar)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Yup, we did it!");
} else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful :(");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to parse in this way:

```
int.TryParse("Grr", out w);
...
```

Comment: in this way, you will avoid the error, but actually I didn't get what exactly you want to do)

Comment: Sure that may avoid an exception, but it will never convert to int.